# Active state on jquery hover code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code that, superbly, changes my image name from image_off.jpg to image_on.jpg on hover. I am using it for a gallery.

```
    $(function(){
     $(".img-swap").hover(
          function(){this.src = this.src.replace("_off","_on");},
          function(){this.src = this.src.replace("_on","_off");
     });
});
```

However I want the image name to stay on image_on.jpg when I click one of the images. Is this possible and is it possible to have it swap back to off when I click another?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps

it will work fine as you want with hover on and off and when you click the img it will be selected and will stay there and hover affect will not work

and when you click the next img all the rest which are selected will be removed and the hover affect will work on that

EDIT ** Changed the code Try it now

```
$(function(){
    $(".img-swap").hover(
    function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass("selected")) {
            this.src = this.src.replace("_off","_on");
        }
    },
    function(){

        if(!$(this).hasClass("selected")) {
            this.src = this.src.replace("_on","_off");
        }

    }).click(function(){
        $('.img-swap').removeClass('selected').attr('src',this.src.replace("_on","_off"));;
        this.src = this.src.replace("_off","_on");
        $(this).addClass("selected").attr('src',this.src.replace("_off","_on"));
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi lori, this works except for it doesn't remove the previous selected state when another is clicked. It appears to require a hover over the last selected image in order to remove the class. demo here: http://www.bandstandserver.net/people/

Comment: Hi Lori, please could you look at my example again? It appears that when you select a person all of the other thumbnails get covered with the selected image. I don't understand why? http://www.bandstandserver.net/people  - this issue didnt show before when i was using only one image to test.

Comment: The system is now working because you have added image through css. and above js code it according you first scenario. this entirealy different situation.

Answer (score 1):

You may use toggle instead of hover :

```
 $(".img-swap").toggle(
      function(){this.src = this.src.replace("_off","_on");},
      function(){this.src = this.src.replace("_on","_off");
 });
```

EDIT : to pin the image on click (prevent it to change back to off), you may do this :

```
$(".img-swap").hover(
      function(){this.src = this.src.replace("_off","_on");},
      function(){if (!pinned) this.src = this.src.replace("_on","_off");
 }).click(){
      $(this).data('pinned': !($(this).data('pinned')||false));
 });
```

Comment: thanks, but that appears to disable the hover state, and doesn't change the state back when another is clicked.

Comment: You want your old behavior and just the click prevent the image to be closed on leaving the hover ?

Comment: Yeah, I still want the hover behaviour, but I want the image name to be _on.jpg as an active state too

Answer (score 0):

Here's some (untested) code:

```
 $(function(){
     $(".img-swap").hover(
      function(){
          this.src = this.src.replace("_off","_on");
      },
      function(){
          if(!this.hasClass("selected")) {
            this.src = this.src.replace("_on","_off");
          }
     }).click(function() {
         $(".img-swap.selected").removeClass("selected");
         this.addClass("selected");
     });
 });
```

What it's doing is adding a `.selected` class to each clicked element. The hover-out function checks this class, and only does the replacement if the image is not selected.

Comment: Hi, this almost works perfectly, however my image doesn't change back to the original state when I hover off the image. Is this easy to add to this code?

Comment: Hmm... so you're saying that non-selected images aren't switching back to their original state when you hover off them?

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply add css hover event for class if you can

.img-swap:hover { src: image_on.jpg }